# Is it possible to permanently disable autoscroll?

Tags: browser, scroll, mouse, autoscroll

This is most often an annoyance when I'm web browsing, but if I middle click somewhere, I get the stupid autoscroll icon. I would like for this to never, ever happen again. I don't know whether this is a windows 10 setting, a mouse driver setting, or a browser setting; but if I could disable it in all three places, that would make me extremely happy.

Answer (score 0):

This probably occurs due to a setting of your mouse driver. So you could  change it easily if your mouse driver would offer a settings dialog.

But the ability to change it depends on the capabilities of your mouse driver, because not all options could be changed in the Windows 10 property dialog.